# ARCore unity: ErrorNotSupportedByConfiguration when saving cloud anchor

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am trying to use Cloud anchors using Unity 2020.1 and ARCore 1.21. I am able to save cloud anchors from the Unity Editor, but I receive this error every time I try to save an anchor from the Android App:

> `2020-11-24 12:41:00.800 2794-2811/? E/Unity: Save failed, Response: ErrorNotSupportedByConfiguration UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object) <>c__DisplayClass13_0:<SaveAllCloudAnchors>b__0(CloudAnchorResult) System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
> GoogleARCore.AsyncTask`1:ThenAction(Action`1)
> CloudAnchorsManager:SaveAllCloudAnchors()
> CloudAnchorsManager:CreateAnchorAtScreenCenter()
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData) UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

I use the `GoogleARCore.CrossPlatform.XPSession.CreateCloudAnchor` method to save the anchor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you!

Comment: Habe you tried to rather directly ask [their support](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues)? Either there or here I suggest you include your actual reproducible code of how exactly you are trying to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not enabling the "Enable Cloud Anchors" option in the configuration file.